# reduce velocity of ball after bounce in collision detection c++ opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, collision-detection

how to reduce velocity of ball after bounce and stop the ball in c++ opengl collision detection and make not to bounce forever??

//Handles all ball-ball collisions

```
void handleBallBallCollisions(vector<Ball*> &balls, Octree* octree) {
vector<BallPair> bps;
potentialBallBallCollisions(bps, balls, octree);
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < bps.size(); i++) {
    BallPair bp = bps[i];

    Ball* b1 = bp.ball1;
    Ball* b2 = bp.ball2;
    if (testBallBallCollision(b1, b2)) {
        //Make the balls reflect off of each other
        Vec3f displacement = (b1->pos - b2->pos).normalize();
        b1->v -= 2 * displacement * b1->v.dot(displacement);
        b2->v -= 2 * displacement * b2->v.dot(displacement);
 }}}   
void applyGravity(vector<Ball*> &balls) {
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
    Ball* ball = balls[i];
    ball->v -= Vec3f( 0, GRAVITY * TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, 0);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a dampening factor to both balls' velocity `Ball::v` after the collision. Physically this would be inelastic scattering where part of the energy gets dissipated as heat.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a variable which defines the **attenuation** of velocity when the object touch each other,
After calculating the new velocity like you did, you'll have to multiply it by the **attenuation** variable

```
float attenuation = 0.8;

b1->v -= 2 * displacement * b1->v.dot(displacement);
b2->v -= 2 * displacement * b2->v.dot(displacement);

b1->v *= attenuation;
b2->v *= attenuation;
```

Comment: Than you very much :)